# What is the function of self publishing websites?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing

Nowadays there are plenty of self publishing websites viz. **Pothi** , **Notionpress**, **Lulu**, etc. My question is; how they differ from a traditional publisher like "**Patra Bharati**" or "**Dey's publishing**" etc?

What I understand by self publishing is that, writing own book, bearing own cost to print and bind it and to circulate it through book fairs and book stores. Where in this process exactly lies the role of self publishing companies?

**My question in short** - if I take help of a company, then how it is self publishing? It is just like traditional publishing isn't?

PS: Can I publish my work without visiting or paying to a self publishing website? is that permissible?

Comment: I recommend reading https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/3677/whats-the-distinction-between-vanity-publishing-and-self-publishing?rq=1